# Union all 3 SUM queries to get total sum from same table and same column but with different clause

Tags: php, mysql, sum, union

I have a table in mysql

```
==================================================
          ID     | TEAM_ID |  PTS | COMPETITION
==================================================
          1      | 1       | 10   | zc
--------------------------------------------------
          2      | 1       | 15   | po
--------------------------------------------------
          3      | 1       | 5    | sp
```

I'm trying to find out the right query to get result of SUM of columns PTS where column team id equals 1. This is what I've got

```
SELECT SUM(pts) FROM 
(SELECT SUM(pts) FROM `stats_2016/2017` WHERE `team_id`='1' AND `competition`='zc'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(pts) FROM `stats_2016/2017` WHERE `team_id`='1' AND `competition`='po'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(pts) FROM `stats_2016/2017` WHERE `team_id`='1' AND `competition`='sp'
)
```

I would like to get a result of 30 (10+15+5)...

Comment: `SELECT SUM(pts) FROM my_table WHERE team_id = 1;` Incidentally, a table called something like stats_2016/2017 is often symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 0):

Three changes:

1. Assign an alias to the inline view (derived table)
2. Assign an alias to the expression in the first SELECT of the inline view. (That alias will be used the column name in the derived table.(
3. in the outer query, reference the column in the inline view by the assigned alias.

---

```
  SELECT SUM(v.totpts) AS totpts 
-- 3.--        ^^^^^^ 
    FROM ( SELECT SUM(pts) AS totpts FROM `stats_2016/2017` ...
-- 2.--                    ^^ ^^^^^^
            UNION ALL
           SELECT SUM(pts) FROM `stats_2016/2017` ...
       ) v
-- 1.--  ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **Group by** and **IN** mysql operator,which work with **dynamic value** of `team_id`
Like this

```
SELECT SUM(pts) FROM `stats_2016/2017` WHERE  `competition` in ('zc','po','sp') 
group by `team_id`
```